# Change highlight color of breakpoint highlights?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When you hit a breakpoint and it highlights that line, I'd like to change that highlight color. It's currently yellow with white text, it would be great if there was a contrast. Please refer to the picture.[image: Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change that yellow background color with this `colorCustomization` in your settings.json:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {

  "editor.stackFrameHighlightBackground": "#5c5b5c"
}
```

For more info, see https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color